# What is the eclipse shortcut for auto-generating a default and field constructor?

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

I had a look at: [Eclipse-Shortcuts](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&q=cache:ONIuWQuH0d0J:eclipse-tools.sourceforge.net/Keyboard_shortcuts_%283.0%29.pdf%20&hl=de&gl=at&pid=bl&srcid=ADGEESiJV5Ksth5keyMfZN72Ww-q1vo728GvYYqXRA5RBS88qV_3y922qUrIKnmvOmRLcr2kkSXgcdFTo5F0xhpe9R39QuRLwDoPXDcHBGhb-T1-_NCgfbujHWiUIoxTosyXyZCGeMvj&sig=AHIEtbR2POLLbNTjEJnxR7oS5S_mL7m-Qw), but I found nothing for generating a constructor.

Whats the shortcut for generating a standard constructor?

Comment: What do you mean by "standard constructor"?

Comment: @A.R.S. I think OP means the default constructor. (no-args)

Comment: There is no default shortcut, but you can assign yours in Window - Preferences - Keys - filter "generate constructor"

Answer (score 96, accepted):

Type the first letter of your class, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse will list suggestions within a combobox. The topmost suggestion is the default constructor. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be done. (I'm using Eclipse Juno and it works.)

Comment: Eclipse Mars; doesn't work. When cycling through suggestion lists, it just suggests `Throwable`, `toString()` and Temp (the *word* Temp, not the constructor for `Temp`)

Answer (score 79):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> and then <kbd>o</kbd> opens the `Generate Constructor using Fields` dialog.

Comment: Actually I prefer this solution. `Alt + Shift + S` followed by `C` (this is the underlined character in the context menu for constructors), followed by `Enter`. No mouse interaction, no searching in lists.

Comment: do you know if we could easily generate a constructor that we pass just the object of the same class and it will copy all fields from it? alternatively I am thinking on reflex

Comment: On Mac, ALT+CMD+S and then Generate Constructor using Fields (you have to click no shortcut on Mac).

Answer (score 15):

`Goto Source ---> Generate constructor using Fields`

Under Source Title bar, select the Generate constructor using Fields option.

**Or**

`Ctrl+Space` which displays the various suggestions possible, from there you can go for the default contructor.

Comment: i found what i wanted in source > Generate Constructors from super class ... thanks for the hint

Comment: better answer as it's cross platform

Answer (score 7):

Ways to Generate **default Constructor** - 
1) Press **Ctl + Space**

Ways to Generate **field Constructor**  - 
1) Press **Alt + Shift + S + O** 
2) **Right click** -> Source -> Generate Constructor using field 
3) Go to **Source menu** -> Generate Constructor using field 
4) Go to **Windows menu** -> Preferences  -> General -> Keys (Write Generate Constructor using field on text field)

Comment: way to go with points-generation. a comment 3 years later then other comments :/

Answer (score 4):

When you hit `CTRL-SPACE` inside your class definition, you will see a drop down.
First option is your Constructor.

Answer (score 3):

For Mac Users it is

Option + Command(⌘) + S **or**

Command(⌘) + Option + S will open the pop up.

Answer (score 2):

Or you could type Ctrl + 3 and type GCUF, what means. Generate Constructor Using Field. Do almost the same to generate getters and setters: Type Ctrl + 3 and type GGAS, what means, Generate Getters And Setters

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways you can follow.

1. easiest:- put the cursor inside the class and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> then click <kbd>Enter</kbd>   (because the first option of the list given by ctrl+ space is contructor)
2. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> type "constr" . hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  you'll get the dialog box of generate constructor. here you can select whether you want the parameter or not. select and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Click <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd>  then click <kbd>o</kbd>
   You will get the same dialog box mentioned in the above (2). Do your selection. hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I think CTRL + 3 is great.

GCFS - generate constructors from a superclass.
GCUF - generate constructor using fields.
GGAS - generate getters and setters.

Answer (score 0):

I think shortcut key to generate Constructors is outdated.  `Alt+Shift+s` and then `press A` opens the `Generate Constructor using Fields` dialog