# How To Make A default Constructor with keyboard Shortcut (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, keyboard-shortcuts

Guys What is the Keyboard Shortcut For Making a default Constructor In any class in eclipse (Universal Keyboard Shortcut for All versions)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the eclipse shortcut for auto-generating a default and field constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322330/what-is-the-eclipse-shortcut-for-auto-generating-a-default-and-field-constructor)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247982/3724636

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type the first letter of your class, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, Eclipse will list suggestions within a combobox. The topmost suggestion is the default constructor. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it will be done. 
**Reference from :https://stackoverflow.com/a/13322359/6102404**

Comment: what is the point of putting the exact same answer that is already there somewhere else on SO?! that usually means that the question is a duplicate. like it clearly is here!

Answer (score 0):

if you have exiting class in your project just press Ctrl+Space in class body and select as per highlighted.

[image: if you have exiting class in your project just press Ctrl+Space in class body and select as per highlighted]

When ever you create new class that time highlighted option select it will create default constructor with class

[image: When ever you create new class that highlighted option select it will create default constructor]