# Automatically generate constructor in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, constructor, autocomplete

suppose i have the following class

```
public class foo{
String a;
String b;
String c;
String d;
... // more Variables

public String getA(){
return a;
}

public void setA(String a){
this.a = a;
}

... // more getters and setters

}
```

what is the easiest way in eclipse to generate the following constructor

```
public foo (String a, String b, String c, ...){
this.a = a;
this.b = b;
this.c = c;
...
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the eclipse shortcut for auto-generating a default and field constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13322330/what-is-the-eclipse-shortcut-for-auto-generating-a-default-and-field-constructor)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59247982/3724636

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Source > Generate Constructor using Fields...* (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>O</kbd>)

> [Create a model class complete with getters/setters and constructors in 35 seconds using the 'Source' menu (with shortcuts!). #EclipseTips](https://twitter.com/EclipseJavaIDE/status/872403485475602432)